# Fullmetal Batman?

Tags: dc, batman

I was "browsing" some profiles on Facebook (as you do) and found this image of Batman and another character which I've never seen before. I've watched quite a few superhero cartoons and maybe one or two computer animated shows but I do not recall Batman being in a computer animation for TV or film.

My guess is that the image is from a computer game, I've played a number of Batman games (way back for SEGA Mega Drive...good times!) to the modern Arkham games but again I haven't come across this. Is it from a show, film, game or even just an artist's creation?

[image: Batman and...]

Comment: -1 due to absolutely no research performed whatsoever.

Comment: @LightnessRacesInOrbit - I did infact do some research in typing terms for searching the image. As i stated in my comment to the answer, I never knew of uploading images for a search. So I learnt something :)

Comment: In Chrome nowadays you literally just right-click on the image and hit "Search Google for this image".

Comment: @LightnessRacesInOrbit - Excellent tip, thank you. I normally use Firefox myself but will install it and keep it in mind when I need to search for images.

Comment: @user35594 Don't even need Chrome (although that makes it easier), it's basically just a shortcut for accessing the search-by-image function in Google's search engine.  Just go to images.google.com in any browser and click on the little camera icon in the search bar.

Comment: @goldPseudo - Thank you for the advice, yes I must have overlooked the icon when searching the images in the good old-fashioned way =)

Comment: @goldPseudo: Yes but the context menu is direct and simple, which was my entire point!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That's part of the [DC Universe online](https://www.dcuniverseonline.com/) trailer from Comic-Con '10. Specifically, that's [Cyborg](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyborg_%28comics%29) beside [Batman](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batman).

Comment: Just to let you know, a Google image search for the image you posted brought this up as the first result.

Comment: Brilliant many thanks! I never knew you could do an image search with Google (I use Yahoo and not even sure if they have this functionality) but I will use that from now on.

Comment: And now you have my upvote. :)